# Does Hot Chocolate uses async EF calls to database when IQueryable [UseFiltering] attributes used

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

```
    [UseFiltering]
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers([ScopedService] DbContext context)
    {
        return context.Users;
    }
```

When we use [UseFiltering], does Hot Chocolate use async EF methods to retrieve data ?

Comment: According to the response to this question (https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/2320) they run asynchronous tasks but don't necessarily take direct advantage of EF's `*Async()` extension methods as of version 10 but were looking to possibly detect and incorporate support to use them with v11.